# Loading theme specific Silverlight Resource Dictionary inside another dictionary at runtime

Tags: c#, silverlight, dynamic, resourcedictionary, hierarchical

I am facing a strange issue in silverlight (SL5) UI styling. I have two files (resource dictionaries) containing same Style keys (different colors). In my resources (eg. buttons.xaml), i want the button styles to pick up color at runtime depending upon the config specific key. The issue is - i have to define one resource dictionary in merged dictionaries in buttons.xaml (otherwise it throws an xaml parse exception for key not found).The buttons pick up color from the resource dictionary defined in merge dictionary and after that if i try to change color by clearing merged dictionary and adding a different one - it wouldn't work (perhaps xaml is compiled into baml already). Currently all my resource dictionaries have properties set as - {Build action - Page, Copt to output directory - Do not copy, Custom Tool - MSBuild :Compile}. Can anyone please help me out if changing the Build action property or CustomTool property make it work. I want the style keys in buttons to be resolved at runtime.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by removing Custom tool property value (set it to empty) and then removed merged dictionaries from buttons.xaml. From App.xaml.cs I would add a resource dictionary corresponding to the color required. A small side effect is designer for views is not able to resolve style keys when adding code in xaml. Hope it saves some time for someone :)